# How do I place super-fish or nice menus in Zen theme main menu?

Tags: 7, navigation, theming

I have successfully downloaded the super fish module and jQuery and placed the jQuery in the libraries folder. I have also activated the module but am having problems placing the super fish blocks in the main menu of my zen theme. Under blocks, there main menu does not appear so am not sure where to place the blocks so that they appear in the main menu.

Comment: Please explain what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: i have tried to rephrase the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Once you have installed Superfish, you must define a number of superfish blocks to be available at /admin/config/user-interface/superfish
2. Then go to the block admin screen and select one of the superfish blocks /admin/structure/block/manage/superfish/1/configure
3. Define the "Menu Parent" under superfish settings to "Main Menu"
4. Define the region you wish to have the menu placed in "Region settings"

Comment: thanks, i have followed your method but the problem am facing is that when i place the block in the navigation bar, this duplicates the main menu (two main menus with the same links). i need the super fish drop down menus to be part of the main menu. any suggestions?

Comment: Edit your theme admin/appearance/settings/[NAME_OF_THEME and uncheck "Main menu" under Toggle display > Enable or disable the display of certain page elements

Comment: i managed to enable the super fish block but decided not to use it in the end because i had problems with theming. However, the problem i have is that the main menu and the secondary links are no longer appearing despite enabling main menu in my main menu {admin/appearance/settings/[NAME_OF_THEME}. Any idea as to what might be the problem?

Comment: i've just resolved the problem. [CLOSED]